# Printing hex dump of a byte array

Tags: c#

The goal is readabilty. Performance is not much of a concern, since it's not going to be used with large amount of data.
Except for degenerate case when the length of the incoming byte array is zero, the dump does not end with a new line character. This is regardless whether ASCII part of the dump is shown or not. The code is also careful not to put any trailing spaces in dump lines, since the dump is intended to be copy-pasted and used as part of other texts.

Code:

```
class Hex
{
    private readonly byte[] _bytes;
    private readonly int _bytesPerLine;
    private readonly bool _showHeader;
    private readonly bool _showOffset;
    private readonly bool _showAscii;

    private readonly int _length;

    private int _index;
    private readonly StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

    private Hex(byte[] bytes, int bytesPerLine, bool showHeader, bool showOffset, bool showAscii)
    {
        _bytes = bytes;
        _bytesPerLine = bytesPerLine;
        _showHeader = showHeader;
        _showOffset = showOffset;
        _showAscii = showAscii;
        _length = bytes.Length;
    }

    public static string Dump(byte[] bytes, int bytesPerLine = 16, bool showHeader = true, bool showOffset = true, bool showAscii = true)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            return "<null>";
        }
        return (new Hex(bytes, bytesPerLine, showHeader, showOffset, showAscii)).Dump();
    }

    private string Dump()
    {
        if (_showHeader)
        {
            WriteHeader();
        }
        WriteBody();
        return _sb.ToString();
    }

    private void WriteHeader()
    {
        if (_showOffset)
        {
            _sb.Append("Offset(h)  ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _bytesPerLine; i++)
        {
            _sb.Append($"{i & 0xFF:X2}");
            if (i + 1 < _bytesPerLine)
            {
                _sb.Append(" ");
            }
        }
        _sb.AppendLine();
    }

    private void WriteBody()
    {
        while (_index < _length)
        {
            if (_index % _bytesPerLine == 0)
            {
                if (_index > 0)
                {
                    if (_showAscii)
                    {
                        WriteAscii();
                    }
                    _sb.AppendLine();
                }

                if (_showOffset)
                {
                    WriteOffset();
                }
            }

            WriteByte();
            if (_index % _bytesPerLine != 0 && _index < _length)
            {
                _sb.Append(" ");
            }
        }

        if (_showAscii)
        {
            WriteAscii();                
        }
    }

    private void WriteOffset()
    {
        _sb.Append($"{_index:X8}   ");
    }

    private void WriteByte()
    {
        _sb.Append($"{_bytes[_index]:X2}");
        _index++;
    }

    private void WriteAscii()
    {
        int backtrack = ((_index-1)/_bytesPerLine)*_bytesPerLine;
        int length = _index - backtrack;

        // This is to fill up last string of the dump if it's shorter than _bytesPerLine
        _sb.Append(new string(' ', (_bytesPerLine - length) * 3));

        _sb.Append("   ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            _sb.Append(Translate(_bytes[backtrack + i]));
        }
    }

    private string Translate(byte b)
    {
        return b < 32 ? "." : Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new[] {b});
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] example = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x=>(byte)x).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(Hex.Dump(example));
```

Sample output:
[image: sample output]

Comment: 1252 is not the ascii codepage but Western European (Windows). You would problably want to use 20127 or Encoding.ASCII?

Comment: @HenrikHansen, yeah, I was sure some one would pick up on this. I chose 1252 over ascii, because 1252 shows something for values more than 0x7F and ascii does not. It makes ascii variable name a misnomer. But I'm happy to live with this in an absence of a better name. What ever is printed out is still ascii, for values less than 0x80 ;)

Comment: I'm happy to meet your expectations then :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thing I like less is that you're forcing caller to deal with a static method. I appreciate that kind of *helpers* but they should be an *alternative* (maybe with default settings) instead of the only way to go. Why?

- If you need more parameters (or to reorder them) then you need to change all calling points.
- If you add complex parameters (such as a formatter) then calling point will quickly become a mess.
- They're viral. If you separate UI from underlying logic and you need to delegate some decisions to different places then you can't pass around an Hex class (where each component/control may fill its own properties) because you have a single method call.
- If a static method becomes complex enough then it will also be harder to test.

I'd also change name from `Hex` to something that describe what your class is doing. `HexStringFormatter`? `HexStringConverter`? I'd give two alternatives:

```
var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
Console.WriteLine(formatter.ConvertToString(example));
```

Note that in this simple case it may even be (an helper method here just save few characters, what's for?):

```
Console.WriteLine(new HexStringFormatter().ConvertToString(example));
```

A more complex case may be like this:

```
var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
formatter.BytesPerLine = 32;
formatter.Content = HexStringFormatterOutput.Ascii
    | HexStringFormatterOutput.Header;
```

These settings may come from UI, now you can return `formatter` object to another method for example in charge to read data without knowing where settings come from...

Note that I also introduced an `enum` instead of multiple boolean properties but it's not *mandatory* and not even always suggested, it depends case by case (I like the `enum` because I can save it in one shot without any effort in my configuration files).

Also you may want to make `Hex` sealed, it's not intended (so far) to be extended.

---

You may accept `IEnumerable<byte>` instead of `byte[]`. Performance impact in `WriteBody()` with `foreach` is negligible, and you do not need `ToArray()` in your example. Not such big gain but it will let you read huge files that does not fit in memory (because you can read them block by block without need to convert to `byte[]` all the content).

In this regard you may want to change the output of your class. Now you need to build a huge output string, if content will be written to disk then it's a waste of resources. Write output to a `TextWriter`. Caller will have responsibility to give you a `StringWriter` if he wants to output to a string. In this case it may be nice to introduce a static helper method for the most common use case. More complex use case may be like this:

```
using (var output = new StringWriter())
{
    var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
    formatter.Output = output;
    formatter.BytesPerLine = 32;

    formatter.ConvertToString(example);
    Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
}
```

HOWEVER note that `HexStringFormatter` accepts a `TextWriter` and `Console.Out` is a `TextWriter`! Code will then be simplified to:

```
var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
formatter.Output = Console.Out;
formatter.BytesPerLine = 32;

formatter.ConvertToString(example);
```

What if you need to write it to a text file?

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter("path_to_file"))
{
    var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
    formatter.Output = stream;
    formatter.BytesPerLine = 32;

    formatter.ConvertToString(example);
}
```

Of course you may want to introduce few helper methods for this (now they can make sense but keep them as simple as possible), something like this:

```
public static string DumpToString(IEnumerable<byte> data)
{
    using (var output = new StringWriter())
    {
        var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
        formatter.Output = output;

        formatter.ConvertToString(data);
        return output.ToString();
    }
}

public static void DumpToFile(string path, IEnumerable<byte> data)
{
    using (var output = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
        formatter.Output = output;

        formatter.ConvertToString(data);
    }
}

public static void DumpToConsole(IEnumerable<byte> data)
{
    var formatter = new HexStringFormatter();
    formatter.Output = Console.Out;

    formatter.ConvertToString(data);
}
```

Now your first example will be again like this:

```
HexStringFormatter.DumpToConsole(
    Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x => (byte)x));
```

---

Few other minor things. Your `Translate()` function should be simplified and made static). Also do not need to get a new encoding for each call, use `Encoding.ASCII`. `b < 32` is clear for most of us but I'd make it explicit. For now let's keep GetString() but see later...

```
private static string Translate(byte b)
{
    if (IsPrintableCharacter(b))
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { b });

    return "."
}

private static bool IsPrintableCharacter(byte b) => b > 32;
```

Now let's think...you're working with ASCII and byte is in range [0...255] then you may directly cast it to `char` (after leave to representation issues you mentioned in your `Console` codepage settings), you avoid to create so many strings and you do not even need any encoding:

```
private static char Translate(byte b)
    => IsPrintableCharacter(b) ? (char)b : '.';
```

Code like `i & 0xFF` in `WriteHeader()` is little bit misleading, IMO. If `_bytesPerLine` contains an invalid value then it should throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when you set it, it shouldn't be silently ignored. Your code will then be simplified everywhere.

About your main loop, you do not need to save `_length` field because you already have the input buffer. I'd also try to give *names* to all those `if`s (=introduce bool locals or separate functions) anyway after refactoring to use `IEnumerable<byte>` it should look much simpler.

Comment: Nice, one hell of a review ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I would have the _index as a class field. Of course it determines the state of the object, but since the Dump() is a one time event and the state is useless afterwards it isn't really to any use to have it there. The result of having it like that is that your WriteAscii() gets unnecessarily "complicated" and in fact needs to "violate" the state as it must backtrack.

Instead I would suggest a WriteBody() as something like this:

```
private void WriteBody()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _length; i += _bytesPerLine) // One line at a time
  {
    WriteOffset(i);
    WriteHex(i);
    WriteAscii(i);
    _sb.AppendLine();
  }
}
```

It is IMO easier to understand because the index is incremented in a more "natural" place, and the Write...() functions knows where they are.

If you insists on _index as a class field, you could do it like this:

```
private void WriteBody()
{
  for (_index = 0; _index < _length; _index += _bytesPerLine) // One line at a time
  {
    WriteOffset();
    WriteHex();
    WriteAscii();
    _sb.AppendLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good one, thanks. The loop the way you wrote it, indeed might end up easier to read. As far as `_index` goes, I'm not insisting on anything, it just felt that in this simple case it's easier to pull it in a class variable, rather than keep passing it between functions. In a more complicated case, I'd probably forgo that, but in this one it felt warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version updated for 2022 that uses `Span<byte>` for the buffer, and a `record` for the class to make it less verbose:

```cs
internal record HexStringConverter(
    Span<byte> bytes,
    int bytesPerLine = 16,
    bool showHeader = true,
    bool showOffset = true,
    bool showAscii = true
)
{
    private int index;
    private readonly StringBuilder sb = new();

    private string Dump()
    {
        if (showHeader)
            WriteHeader();
        WriteBody();
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void WriteHeader()
    {
        if (showOffset)
            sb.Append("Offset(h)  ");

        for (var i = 0; i < bytesPerLine; i++)
        {
            sb.Append($"{i & 0xFF:X2}");
            if (i + 1 < bytesPerLine)
                sb.Append(' ');
        }

        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    private void WriteBody()
    {
        while (index < bytes.Length)
        {
            if (index % bytesPerLine == 0)
            {
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    if (showAscii)
                        WriteAscii();
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }

                if (showOffset)
                    WriteOffset();
            }

            WriteByte();
            if (index % bytesPerLine != 0 && index < bytes.Length)
                sb.Append(' ');
        }

        if (showAscii)
            WriteAscii();
    }

    private void WriteOffset()
    {
        sb.Append($"{index:X8}   ");
    }

    private void WriteByte()
    {
        sb.Append($"{bytes[index]:X2}");
        index++;
    }

    private void WriteAscii()
    {
        var backtrack = (index - 1) / bytesPerLine * bytesPerLine;
        var length = index - backtrack;

        // This is to fill up last string of the dump if it's shorter than _bytesPerLine
        sb.Append(new string(' ', (bytesPerLine - length) * 3));

        sb.Append("   ");
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sb.Append(Translate(bytes[backtrack + i]));
    }

    private static char Translate(byte b)
    {
        return IsPrintableCharacter(b) ? (char)b : '.';
    }

    private static bool IsPrintableCharacter(byte c)
    {
        return c > 32;
    }
}
```